# Swift Collection API: extend with a computed variable: type error

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, generics, swift-protocols

I have a following method:

```
private func returnNilIfEmpty<T: Collection>(_ collection: T?) -> T? {
    guard let collection = collection else { return nil }
    return collection.isEmpty ? nil : collection
}
```

I'd like to extend the `Collection` API to use a computed variable to extract the non-empty value like this:

```
extension Collection {
    var nonEmptyValue: Collection? {
        returnNilIfEmpty(self)
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting the error:

> Protocol 'Collection' can only be used as a generic constraint because
> it has Self or associated type requirements

Which is clear, as the outer `Collection` can be any collection (e.g. an `[Int]`) while the collection inside the `returnNilIfEmpty` can be e.g. a `String`.

The question is how can I enforce the rule that the `Collection` returned via `nonEmptyValue` and the one returned via `returnNilIfEmpty` of the same type, so that I can get rid of this compiler error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is appropriate to use `Self` here:

```
extension Collection {
    var nonEmptyValue: Self? {
        returnNilIfEmpty(self)
    }
}
```

If e.g. you did `Set([1,2,3]).nonEmptyValue`, you'd expect to get a `Set<Int>?` rather than a general `Collection?` (you don't even know what kind of elements this type contains or anything like that!), wouldn't you?

Comment: Yes, thank you, I understand the problem clearly, I just couldn't figure out the syntax for the computed variable (but obviously, I have that fixed for the function).

I actually came up with the same solution like you (and even simplified it further now). Marking your answer as accepted :)

Comment: @RichardTopchii Oh `returnNilIfEmpty` was only there for the `Collection` extension? I was just going to point out that you can also implement `returnNilIfEmpty` as an extension on `Collection?` by doing `extension Optional where Wrapped == Collection`.

Comment: Not really, I was just experimenting and came up with the function first. I didn't even have to write `where Wrapped == Collection`, I guess it's already implemented in Swift, so that it works on optionals too

Comment: @RichardTopchii Actually, ignore what I just said. Just realised implementing `returnNilIfEmpty` as an optional extension is rather unnecessary, since it's equivalent to optional chaining: `someOptionalCollection?.nonEmptyValue`.

Comment: Yeah, absolutely, that's how I went further

Answer (score 1):

Using `Self` solves the issue, since it points to the concrete type of the collection:

```
import Foundation

extension Collection {
    var nonEmptyValue: Self? {
        returnNilIfEmpty(self)
    }
}

func returnNilIfEmpty<T: Collection>(_ collection: T?) -> T? {
    guard let collection = collection else { return nil } // nil -> return nil
    return collection.isEmpty ? nil : collection // return nil if empty
}
```

Simplified even further:

```
import Foundation

extension Collection {
    ///
    var nonEmptyValue: Self? {
        self.isEmpty ? nil : self
    }
}
```